# Send and receive emails from localhost using PHP running XAMPP

Tags: php, email, localhost

I am trying to make an application which can parse emails and update the database. I tried to set up the localhost to send and receive emails so that I can carry on from there. I am unable to do that. I tried configuring Outlook, Thunderbird to set up local email system using mercury mail server. Its not working properly.

I would like to have a step by step procedure explaining how to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

hi try this it will work.....
download phpmailer.zip
github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

simple code for send mail:

```
<?php
    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             
    $mail->Username = 'ur@domain.com';                           
    $mail->Password = 'ur password';                           
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                          
    $mail->From = 'ur@domain.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'mailer';
    $mail->addAddress('aa@example.com');  
    $mail->addAddress('bb@example.com');             
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For sending emails via SMTP in PHP you only have to change `SMTP = localhost` in the `[mail function]` section of PHP.INI to the SMTP of your ISP. Also you need to change the port for some ISPs that block the default port (25). Exemple:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = mail.mydomain.com
smtp_port = 2525
```

Comment: i did that as well... but something is wrong!! I followed these steps -> http://www.tech2all.com/2006/03/12/how-to-setup-your-own-e-mail-server/#idc-cover but not working

Comment: I did that numerous times in the past with success. Maybe your ISP block port 25?

Answer (score 0):

You could try configuring a local mail server that allows you to sent to and receive from localhost.

Have a look at this [link](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/23.html) on how to set this up

Answer (score 0):

I found a easy solution for this try this application
http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

i found a tutorial about it it works fine with me

http://www.synet.sk/php/en/155-testing-php-mail-on-localhost-with-fake-smtp-server-hMailServer-and-outlook